# How do I link a token with a sentence in Spacy

Tags: spacy

I would like to build a keyword list from tokens with a lookup back to the sentence where they came from,  thanks

Comment: Please add what you have so far

Answer (score 2):

You can get the sentences from `token.doc.sents`, and then find the first one that starts on or after your token. You can make this more convenient by adding an extension attribute to `token` like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Token

def get_sentence(token):
    for sent in token.doc.sents:
        if sent.start <= token.i:
            return sent

# Add a computed property, which will be accessible as token._.sent
Token.set_extension('sent', getter=get_sentence)

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'Sentence one. Sentence two.')
print(list(doc.sents))
print(doc[0]._.sent)
print(doc[-1]._.sent)
```